# How do I recreate this Microsoft Word button in VSTO C#?

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, office-addins, ribbonx

I need to recreate this Microsoft Word button in VSTO C#

[color button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojCLs.png)

I have tried all I know, like using menus, galleries and dropdowns but they don't give me the flexibility and functionalities to replicate the same button.
Surely there must be a easy way to populate an empty control with all the content of that button in one line of code or something.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) doesn't provide anything for that. There is no color picker control available for the ribbon. The best what you could do is to create a task pane with any .net control (a custom color picker control) or standard [ColorDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.colordialog?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=windowsdesktop-7.0) class which is available out of the box.

See [How to: Add a custom task pane to an application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-add-a-custom-task-pane-to-an-application?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp) for more information.

Comment: hi thank you for your reply. I am looking to reproduce the button I have attached in the link and nothing more. Is it possible to make it?

Comment: Nope. The best what you could do is to use the dropdown or menu control  on the ribbon.